# Clear memory allocated by plotting in IPython

Tags: python, memory, matplotlib, ipython, qtconsole

I'm plotting some large plots in IPython QtConsole (and Notebook). These take up a lot of memory, but once they are plotted I don't need them any more and they can go.

**How can I free up memory?**

*None* of the following  works:

```
close()
clf()
cla()
%reset
```

The only thing that frees the memory is **restarting the kernel**, which I don't always want to do (say I worked through a long process to get to a specific point) [To be precise, `%reset` does free up some memory, but not as much as restarting the kernel].

How to replicate the problem:

```
plot(arange(2e7))
```

You may need a bigger or a smaller number to notice a big impact on your system memory.

Comment: make sure nothing is holding references to the artist objects returned by `plot`.

Comment: I'm testing by literally just running the line `plot(arange(2e7))` in a pylab console (`ipython --pylab=inline`, for example), no more. No references (that I know of).

Comment: `plot` returns artists, ipython is probably capturing the in the output section.  I assume you see something like `Out [N]: line2D object`?  Also, please stop using pylab.

Comment: Yes, capturing the artist in a variable, deleting it and collecting garbage does help. `x = plot(arange(2e7)); del x; gc.collect()` after `import gc`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After reading tcaswell's comment, I investigated a bit more what IPython is storing. This is my method:

```
## start afresh

## what variables are there before calling plot()?
## make sure you copy() otherwise it's just a reference.
before = vars().copy()

plt.plot(range(10))

## now, what's available after?
after = vars().copy()

## print out the differences
for k in after.keys():
  if k not in before.keys():
    print k

## or a bit more compact
print set(after.keys()) - set(before.keys())
```

Result is:

```
before
_i2
_i3
_2
```

Where `_i*` are string of the inputs and `_n` (with `n` a number) are the strings of the outputs. 
Removing those items and garbage collecting does *not* seem to free up memory though.